# Modulus operator over int

Tags: c++

Is it possible that after performing a modulus(%) of 10^9 + 7 over a number then number might still be out of range.

I was doing this question on CodeChef  http://www.codechef.com/problems/FIRESC and was getting a wrong answer, after looking at the authors solution I changed my final answer type to long long int to int and got a correct answer. Why did that happen?

Comment: My first instinct is that you're using a variable that has too small of a width for your calculation. Try an unsigned long long. The reason it happens is because of how many bits each variable can represent. int can only do ~65k or so, and long int can only represent up to about ~4.5b or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform multiplications like `result = (result * x) % MOD` where both `result` and `x` can be up to `MOD - 1`, the intermediate expression `result * x` can be up to `(MOD - 1)` squared. And for modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7, this surely does not fit into a 32-bit integer type. Thus it is calculated incorrectly: basically, you get not `result * x`, but the same quantity modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

For example, from a mathematical point of view, (100,001 * 100,001) modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 is 199,931, but when calculated in a 32-bit integer, 100,001 * 100,001 becomes 1,410,265,409, and taking it modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 gives 410,265,402.